# MySQL Join - Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql

while trying to join two tables I am getting following error. I am not sure why it's showing me this error and nothing seems wrong with the query.

**mysql version: 5.0**

**Query**

```
SELECT Employee.Name
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Employee
ON Employee.DepartmentID=Dept.id;
```

**Employee Table**

```
Id  int(11)
Name    varchar(20)
Gender  varchar(20)
Salary  int(11)
DepartmentID    int(11)
```

**Dept Table**

```
id  int(11)
DeptName    varchar(20)
DeptLoc varchar(20)
DeptHead    varchar(20)
```

Following is the error message I am getting while executing the query.

> [Code: 1066, SQL State: 42000]  Not unique table/alias: 'Employee'

Comment: are you sure you don't mean INNER JOIN Dept instead of INNER JOIN Eemployee

Answer (score 3):

You are Joining `Employee` table to itself.

But you are probably want to join to `Dept` table:

```
SELECT 
  e.Name, 
  d.DeptName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Dept d
ON e.DepartmentID = d.id
```